# Deleting or renaming model version in XCode 7

Tags: xcode, core-data, xcode7

I can't seem to find any way to delete or rename a Core Data version. It is not the current model version. Once you add a version, if you right-click it 'delete' is disabled. You also can't click it a second time to rename. I can delete the version in the package by opening it in Finder, but then it still stays there as deleted. I suspect I will have to edit the project file using Text Edit.

Is there a cleaner way to delete an unwanted Core Data version in XCode 7?

Comment: Some of the answers in [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708392/how-to-delete-an-old-unused-data-model-version-in-xcode-4) are quite old but possibly still valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so @AliBeadle was right. I had seen the [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7708392/how-to-delete-an-old-unused-data-model-version-in-xcode-4) before, but didn't read closely enough. I had not noticed the distinction between `.xcdatamodeld` and just `.xcdatamodel`, so I tried to remove the latter which is not possible. If you remove the whole model (ie. all versions), then delete the version from the package, and then add the model back in - all is well!