# How to clear and reset Core Data data models

Tags: xcode, core-data

I have now >45 different versions of xcdatamodel in Xcode, of which 44 of them are no longer required, as I've eseentially gone for the drop/create approach of the entire database. How can I clear these out, without Xcode kicking up a fuss?

See the linked image:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1bpdhf9bax6iicb/Screenshot%202014-05-23%2013.24.45.png

Comment: Don't believe there's much reason to version in development, other than practice.  Consider store options `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` and `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption` if you were getting annoyed at blowing away the store every time you made a model tweak.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting core data version xcdatamodel files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712123/deleting-core-data-version-xcdatamodel-files)

Answer (score 6):

Note: this approach is waaaaayyyy simpler: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6712191/84783, but if you wanna get up to your elbows with project files, try my steps below.

---

I think they keep these around for current installations to do model migrations. Sadly I think you have some manual project file hacking.

- Make sure you have the model you want set as the current model
- Close Xcode
- Right click on "Model.xcdatamodeld" in Finder
- Choose Show Package Contents
- Delete the models you no longer want
- Right click on "MyProject.xcodeproj"
- Choose Show Package Contents
- Open project.pbxproj in a text editor
- Search for ".xcdatamodel" and delete entries (Model.xcdatamodel and "Model X.xcdatamodel") no longer in use
- Careful not to delete ".xcdatamodeld" files

Hope this helps, Rob